# Multiple feature development branch in subversion

Tags: svn, build, merge, branch

G'day,

Can the following strategy be implemented with subversion?

1. A stable trunk that holds the production version of an application
2. A separate development branch that holds *multiple* features
3. Keep the development branch in synch with the stable trunk
4. Merge/copy *individual* features from the development branch to the trunk as they become production-ready

The reason for wanting 2. is that we also need an "early release" build that holds all the features currently in development.

The standard [feature branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html) pattern doesn't suffice.  The branch holds a single feature and should be deleted once the feature is merged into the stable trunk.  I've read that you *can* continue to use a branch after a `merge --reintegrate` but it's not recommended.

I was wondering whether (file system) copying individual features from the development branch to a working copy of the trunk (build, test, commit, then immediately synch the branch with the trunk) would be possible?  The synch would result in conflicts but easily resolved ones.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

You can make as many branches as you want, there's nothing special about the names "trunk" and "feature". In your case I'd say make several feature branches, perhaps named after the feature ticket item in your tracker.

Comment: Thanks Satya.  You're right about the distinction between trunk and branches being in name only and I appreciate that.  However, I don't see how I can (easily) maintain an "early access" release that holds **all** the features under development when each feature resides on a separate branch.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly: You could have trunk, devel, earlyaccess, f1, f2, ... fn branches. Merge f1 through fn with earlyaccess whenever ready. Keep devel in sync with trunk. Merge f1 through fn into trunk. Hmm, seems like there would be sync issues, lots of conflicts. And that's assuming I understand what you want. Hmm, use git instead? (I'm an svn person, so it's not that kind of advocacy :-)

Comment: Yes, I think you understand the problem correctly, and thanks for the suggestion but I reckon the synch and conflict issues will make it too difficult in practise.  Unfortunately, git is not an option, so in the absence of any other suggestions I'll go with my original proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your strategy can be implemented with subversion. But it will be quite inefficient since you will have to list all the commits (or commit ranges) related to the feature being merged, in the the merge command.

A much better strategy is with single feature branches. You can have as many branches as you want and merge them at any time individually. And you don't have to list the commits when doing so since you typically will merge the whole set of changes of each branch.

People often argue that branching is to be avoided because of the difficulty to merge back. But cherry-picking from a multiple feature branch is even more unpleasing.